# How to write a custom validator to prevent saving same day appointments at past times in Rails 4 app?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning Rails while coding my first app.  My app has an apppointment model, which is a join table with the following columns (and datatypes):  date (date), starts_at (time), and ends_at (time).  I'm trying to write a method for a custom validation to prevent users from inadvertantly scheduling SAME day appointments for starts_at times that are in the past. In other words, the starts_at time for a same day appointment must always be greater than the current time of day.

For example:  Say today is Monday, Jan. 12, 2015, and the current time is 12:00 pm.  I need the model validation to prevent a user from scheduling an appointment for today at say 6:30 am, because that time is already past (per the server's time zone).

Here's my unsuccessful attempt at writing a custom validation & method to accomplish the objective:

```
validate :past_time_appointment

private

def past_time_appointment
   if self.date == Date.current  && self.starts_at < Time.now        
   errors.add(:starts_at, "can't be in the past")          
   end
end
```

This code doesn't work properly.  While researching the issue, I found another Stackoverflow post which addressed the problem, but it was not a Rails project. It was related to an ASP.NET MVC 1 application in C#.

What's the best way to approach this problem in Rails 4? My code doesn't work, but I'm not sure why.  I'd appreciate any advice and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after thinking about it anew.  I discarded my previous method and wrote a new one:

```
  private

  def today_appointment
    self.date == Date.current    
  end
```

then I used the Validates_Timeliness gem ( https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness ) to call the method:

```
validates_time :starts_at, :after => :now, :if => :today_appointment
```

Placing the validation in my Appointment model prevents a user from saving a same day appointment which has a "starts_at" time in the past. The ":if" statement in the validation "scopes" it to the current day only. This is to prevent the validation from blocking appointments on other days.  This approach accomplishes my objective. I hope this helps someone else who face this problem in the future.